# Failed to load json resource - Need Assistance

Tags: javascript, html, json

Hey Im a begginer when it comes to new age html code (i consider json and javascript code new age, because i learned on just straight html code). Well What im doing is trying to get all the data from my .json file and put in a table, but it keeps saying i cannot load resource and it says the .json file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" charset="text">       </meta>
  <title> - Jason Onto HTML Displayed</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#DisplyEmp").click(function() {
          $.getJSON("Localhost/Homework_1_second_attempt.json", function(data) {
              for(emp in data.albums) {
                  console.log(data.albums[emp]);
                  var newRow = "<tr>"+
                                  "<td>"+data.albums[emp].title+"</td>"+
                                  "<td>"+data.albums[emp].artist+"</td>"+
                                  "<td>"+data.albums[emp].songs+"</td>"+
                               "</tr>";
                  $("#EmpNewTable").append(newRow);
              } 
          });
      });
  });
</script>


</head>
<body>
<table id="EmpNewTable" border="2"> 
<tr> 
  <th>Artist</th>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>Songs</th>
</tr> 
</table><br /><br /> 
<input type="button" id="DisplyEmp" value="Display" />

</body></html>
```

thank you everyone for helping me with my problem

Comment: The URL you supply to `.getJSON` needs to be valid. What you have currently simply won't work. Try something like `.getJSON('Homework_1_second_attempt.json', function(...`. This presumes that you are running a server, and that the JSON file is in the same relative location as the calling page.

Comment: check your browser console to see whether it is giving a same origin policy violation error

Comment: use var emp in your loop, please check your loop , i think its incorrect

Comment: your json url must be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Due to security concerns, browsers will not allow you to ever load resources from any domain other than your own. That includes the `file:///` "protocol".

To do this, you will need to run a server.  From the looks of it, maybe you are running this on `http://localhost`. Then change your ajax url to

```
$.getJSON("/Homework_1_second_attempt.json...
```

The relative path will start at the same location as the file you are viewing.

Comment: the console.log, anyways i changed the code for the "get jquery code" to-  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
 and how it says 
OPTIONS file:///C:/Homework_1_second_attempt.json  jquery-latest.min.js:5
b.ajaxTransport.send jquery-latest.min.js:5
b.extend.ajax jquery-latest.min.js:5
b.each.b.(anonymous function) jquery-latest.min.js:5
b.extend.getJSON jquery-latest.min.js:5
(anonymous function) Version%204.0.html:12
b.event.dispatch jquery-latest.min.js:3
b.event.add.v.handle

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
var rows = '';
for(emp in data.albums) {
    rows += "<tr>"+
                "<td>"+emp.title+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+emp.artist+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+emp.songs+"</td>"+
            "</tr>";
}
$("#EmpNewTable").append(rows);
```

Comment: Or if you know how `for ... in ...` works. `emp` is the *key*, not the *value*.